# how to distinct same keys in first line with d3.csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

`d3.csv` recognizes the first line as a key name automatically.
Then, if the first line includes same name keys, we cannot read all data and `d3.csv` reads only one column.

#### csv example (`Z` are same keys)

```
X,Y,Z,Z
1,4,7,10
2,5,8,11
3,6,9,12
```

I want to read both of the datum which correspond to the same keys (`Z` in this example).
Maybe we cannot extract "10,11,12" using the `d3.csv` function.

Could you tell me how to read both of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `d3.csv` will not be able to extract the complete data.

However, if you have a custom data format, then use [d3.text](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_text) to load the data as a text file.
Then you can parse it in your custom format using [d3.csv.parseRows](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-parseRows).

This will give you an array of arrays which you can then [`d3.transpose`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_transpose) to find your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @musically_ut's answer, you could do something like the following:

```
d3.text("txt.csv", function(err, txt){
    var rows = d3.csv.parseRows(txt),
        header = rows.shift(),
        data = rows.map(function(r){
            var obj = {};
            r.forEach(function(c, i){
                if (!(header[i] in obj))
                    obj[header[i]] = c;
                else
                    obj[header[i]] +=  " " + c;
            });
            return obj;
        });
});
```

Here, like with `d3.csv`, you are creating an object for each row of the CSV file with keys corresponding to the column names. Unlike with `d3.csv`, if two columns have the same name, this method just appends the data in both columns together (see example below).

If you output the resulting `data` using this method, you get the following:

```
>> console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
[{"X":"1","Y":"4","Z":"7 10"},
 {"X":"2","Y":"5","Z":"8 11"},
 {"X":"3","Y":"6","Z":"9 12"}
]
```